# How do I find cheap flights when I don't care about the date?

Tags: air-travel, budget, online-resources

I more often than not don't really care about travel times, I would happily seek out the cheapest time within a 2-3 month period.

All the online sites I come across give you the option to select a date with a variation of -7/+7 days.

I would like to know if there is a site that will just find me the cheapest prices but that is more relaxed on the date.

I am from the UK, any specific sites are preferred.

Comment: The question maybe a duplicate the answer however is not. I am glad i found out about kayak explore.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.kayak.com/explore/

The link above should provide the search function you need.  Simply input a starting airport like LHR and you can limit the results by month, price, activity, etc.

Comment: Kayak's explorer tells me I can go from Chicago to Istanbul for $712.  But if I click on that and spend 15 minutes trying different dates and durations, the best thing I can find is $910.